# Error: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server

Tags: java, mongodb

In the connection the database and collection are found, but this is giving this error ..

```
INFORMAÇÕES: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server xarquigo01f:27017com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: xarquigo01f
at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddress(ServerAddress.java:188)
at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:57)
at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58)
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:113)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: is your network is kind of unstable?

Comment: No, it's from the company where I do internships.

Comment: well it looks like a network issue...

Comment: how of can you reproduce that?

Comment: But what exactly would it be?

Comment: I am doing a query in the database.

Comment: Can you connect to the database using Telnet?

Comment: I am not allowed to communicate with the database via telnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted out. The problem was on the server, I just switched server and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exception while trying to host my jar on Amazon EBS. I thought it was a security group problem and tried over and over changing what was allowed in the inbound and failed to solve. My database I'm using is hosted by MongoDB Atlas. I forgot that I only allowed specific addresses to access the database. As soon as I allowed the Amazon EBS address and restarted the app it was able to connect.